# Product of primes

Tags: primes

I need to write a code that for the given number n checks whether its absolute value can be written as product of three prime numbers(those prime numbers dont need to be different but they can). Here is the code i found but i dont understand it.

If this is correct i dont know why i and j need to be prime numbers here. Looking these loops they can be not prime number as well.
`for(i=2;i<n/2;i++) {`
   `for(j=2;j<n/2;j++) {`
`if(i*(j*j)==Math.abs(n));`

Comment: What language are you using? Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: That you **found** some code does **not** mean it's correct.

Comment: First find all the prime factors of the number you are given.  Second, try to find any combination of three of those factors that give the original number.

Comment: Factor the number into its [canonical representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer), then add up the exponents to see if they sum to 3.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Clearly (2) or (3) prime factors can be identical; e.g., `27 = 3 x 3 x 3`. If (n) is even, then (2) is a factor - but then: `8 = 2 x 2 x 2` also satisfies the criteria. What is the potential range of (n)? If it's not too large, and is a composite, it's feasible to test divisibility up to floor(sqrt(n)). Provide a first, good attempt using code, *after* thinking for a while with a pen and paper. Then people can help you work on refining your code, and looking for 'edge' cases where things tend to break.